# Read a Python List from a config file

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a config file as below with a List in it.

```
[my_variables]
dict = [{'name': 'Jack', 'age': 26}, {'name': 'Ray', 'age': 34}, {'name': 'Aby', 'age': 18}]
```

I'm trying to read this List using ConfigParser. But, it's read as a string. How can I read it as a List as is.

```
>>> import ConfigParser, os
>>> config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.readfp(open('myConfig.properties'))
>>> a = config.get('my_variables', 'dict')
>>> a
"[{'name': 'Jack', 'age': 26}, {'name': 'Ray', 'age': 34}, {'name': 'Aby', 'age': 18}]"

>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
```

**Expected Result :** a Should be a list as mentioned.

Please suggest any way to do it.

Thanks....

Comment: ``import json; json.loads(a)`` ?

Comment: This is a list, not dict......Try `import ast` and `ast.literal_eval(open('myConfig.properties').read())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked...

```
import ConfigParser, os
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(open('myConfig.properties'))
a = config.get('my_variables', 'dict')
b = ast.literal_eval(a)
b
[{'age': 26, 'name': 'Jack'}, {'age': 34, 'name': 'Ray'}, {'age': 18, 'name': 'Aby'}]


type(b)
<type 'list'>
```